# Can't browse website in iis6

Tags: iis, iis-6

When I browse my website it shows me a directory listing instead of web pages:

[image]

How do I stop this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're seeing a directory listing rather than the Default.aspx page being loaded up then you're missing "Default.aspx" as a default document. Check out [Setting Up Default Documents in IIS6](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/dc6eb1b4-9028-4308-9935-52b64edfad36.mspx?mfr=true).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've got *Directory Browsing* turned on:

[image]

Open the site properties and select the Home Directory tab. Uncheck "Directory Browsing".